# How to split text only until the first split in a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, split

I have a data-set in which there are two columns: `Industry Classifications` and `Stock Tickers`. A company has multiple tags in its `Industry Classification` column separated by a `;` delimiter. I want to select only the first tag.

```
import pandas as pd
training = pd.read_excel('Training Data.xlsx')
```

Current file structure: (This is sample of the column)

```
Industry Classifications
Beauty Care Products (Primary); Consumer Staples (Primary); Hair Care Products (Primary);

Catalog Flowers, Gifts and Novelties (Primary); Catalog Hobbies, Games and Toy Retail (Primary);

Information Technology (Primary); Internet Software and Services (Primary);
Casualty (Primary); Financials (Primary); Fire and Marine Insurance (Primary); 

Commercial and Professional Services (Primary); Commercial Services and Supplies (Primary); 

Banks (Primary); Banks (Primary); Diversified Banks (Primary); Financials (Primary); 

Application Software (Primary); Information Technology (Primary); Software (Primary);

Commercial and Professional Services (Primary); Consulting Services (Primary); Industrials (Primary);

Banks (Primary); Banks (Primary); Financials (Primary); National and State Commercial Banks (Primary);
```

Expected output:

```
Industry Classifications

Beauty Care Products (Primary)

Catalog Flowers

Information Technology (Primary)

Casualty (Primary)

Commercial and Professional Services (Primary) 

Banks (Primary); Banks (Primary)

Application Software (Primary)

Commercial and Professional Services (Primary)

Banks (Primary); Banks (Primary)
```

Comment: Its a dupe, try df['col'].str.split(';').str[0]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could extract your first column just as you are already doing, and then split on the semicolon and take the first element of the result.

```
first_tag = col.split(';')[0]
```